# How do I align my radio button with associated text?

Tags: css

I am trying to put two radio buttons on my form. The HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
<form action="">
  <legend>Type your info here</legend>
  <p>
    <label>Do you have a student loan?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="loan" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="loan" value="no">No<br>
  </p>
</form>
</div>
```

When I run this, it turns out like this:

[image]

I also currently have some CSS, which may be causing the problem (I don't know if it is).

```
.container{
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
}

.container input{
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

So the question is: can someone please let me know how I could get the buttons to sit next to the "yes" and "no" texts/labels?

Comment: Thank you for the edit @chipChocolate.py. Not sure what happened there.

Comment: Oh my mistake. It shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, you're using `width:100%;` in all input element which is causing you that. Just use width 100% in input whose type is text as per your requirement:

```
.container input[type="text"]{
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```